# Cannot locate static scripts with golang server

Tags: javascript, go

I wrote a golang webserver and I was serving static resources before, but after changing my project structure, that no longer works.

This is my project structure

```
ProjectFolder/
    node_modules/
    scripts/
       test.es6.js
    server/
       handlers.go
       main.go
       routes.go
    static/
       scripts/
          test.js
          test.js.map
    Gruntfile.js
    index.html
    package.json
```

This is my index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/test.js"</script>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

This is my routes.go

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    for pathName, pathValue := range staticPaths {
        pathPrefix := "/" + pathName + "/"
        fmt.Println(pathPrefix)
        fmt.Println(pathValue)
        router.PathPrefix(pathPrefix).Handler(http.StripPrefix(pathPrefix, http.FileServer(http.Dir(pathValue))))
    }


    // router.PathPrefix("/static/scripts").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/scripts/")))
    return router
}

var staticDirectory = "/static"

var staticPaths = map[string]string{
    "scripts": staticDirectory + "/scripts/",
}

var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
}
```

When I hit localhost:8200, I get a 404 when loading test.js, but index.html is getting hit.

Before, this was an issue with not using http.FileServer to serve static resources, but I am using it now.

I've tried other variations of the path in index.html

```
src= "static/scripts/test.js"
src= "../static/scripts/test.js"
```

What is going on?

EDIT-

I've simplified everything and tried to do this

router.Handle("../static/scripts", http.StripPrefix("../static/scripts", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))

But that still isn't working.

Comment: Use the full path to your static dir, not a relative path - e.g. not `../static`

Comment: use relative path in your html for javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// Create new router.
gorillaMux := mux.NewRouter()

// Match /res/ prefix to local /res/ folder.
gorillaMux.PathPrefix("/res/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/res/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./res/"))))
```

This will make `http://example.com/res/js/script.js` look for `./res/js/script.js`

So, you have to fully qualify you resources in your HTML: `src= "/static/scripts/test.js"`